# FileInput Button with selectInput in shiny..!

Tags: shiny, rstudio

I am trying to take the speed variable from the "car" data set which I am uploading to the application. Basically Under select speed: I would like to have all the numbers appearing in the dataset$speed. Under selecInput, the choices should depend upond the data set I am uploading using fileInput. How can I complete this task. For now I have added  the choices as 1,2,3. In theory there should be all values of the speed variable of cars data set.

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
##the file I am uploading 
data(cars)
dataset=write.csv(cars, "dataset.csv")


ui=fluidPage( 

actionButton("upload", "Upload File"),
bsModal("uploadFile", " ", "upload", 
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
fileInput("file","Choose file to upload")

),
mainPanel(
tableOutput("contents")
)
)
),  



sidebarLayout(

sidebarPanel(

column(3, selectInput("selectElement", "Select speed:", c(1,2,3),multiple = 
T, selectize = F)

)
),

mainPanel(
)
)
)

server=function(input,output,session){

output$contents <- renderTable({

inFile <- input$file

if (is.null(inFile))
return(NULL)

read.csv(inFile$datapath)
})
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 1):

My apologies in advance for a somewhat incomplete response: see below.

First of all, an answer to your query:

If you have a dataset like cars, to identify the "speed" labels you can do:

```
labls <- unique(cars$speed)
...
selectInput("selectElement", "Select speed:", labls, multiple = 
                          T, selectize = F)
```

I was hoping to post a complete example, but the current logic (maybe because of the limited code posted?) does not seems right: how can the app a) leave to the user to select which file to use; and at the same time b) already filter for speed?
Of course it is possible that you plan to display datasets that have all a column called "speed", then it would make sense :)

Additionally, but this was not part of your question, you appear to use modal dialogues through the package shinyBS.

Since version 0.14 of shiny (around October 2016) shiny has a very good modal function and personally I think it would be better to use the native function instead.

I thougth to post a simple example derived from your code (but with the selectInput for speed commented out because, as mentioned, it does not appear right in the context of the example  posted).

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets) 
data(cars)
dataset = write.csv(cars, "dataset.csv")  

labls <- unique(cars$speed) # I left this in the code

ui=fluidPage( 
  sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
         actionButton("upload", "Upload File") 
    ),

  mainPanel(tableOutput("contents") )
))
server=function(input,output,session){
# Show modal when button is clicked.
observeEvent(input$upload, {
  showModal(dataModal())
  })
dataModal <- function(failed = FALSE) {
  modalDialog(
    fileInput('inputId', label=NULL, multiple = FALSE, accept = NULL, width =      NULL, buttonLabel = "Browse...", placeholder = "No file selected")
# , selectInput("selectElement", "Select speed:", labls, multiple = 
#                               T, selectize = F)
  )
}  
output$contents <- renderTable({
if (length(input$inputId )== 0) return(NULL) 
    inFile <- input$inputId   
# if (is.null(input$selectElement )) return(NULL)    
input$inputId 
})
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: It works for me. I'm using Chrome. Extract from sessionInfo().  Please check if you have same releases (especially shiny).
>sessionInfo()R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
(...)
other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.0.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] R6_2.2.0        htmltools_0.3.5 tools_3.3.3     Rcpp_0.12.10   
[5] jsonlite_1.4    digest_0.6.12   xtable_1.8-2    httpuv_1.3.3   
[9] mime_0.5